# How to loop through, match and replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all, regex-group

I have multiple strings with same curly braces I want to replace them as dynamic if I get the count as 1 then need to replace the first occurrence, If count as 2 then replaces the second occurrence as so on until condition satisfies.

```
<?php

include_once("con.php");
$db = new Da();

$con = $db->con();

$String = "{{ONE}} {{TWO}} {{THREE}} {{FOUR}} {{FIVE}} {{SIX}}";

 $Count = 1;
 if(preg_match_all("/\{\{[^{}]+\}\}/", $lclString, $matches)) {

    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        $Count++;
        $Query = "SELECT link FROM student WHERE linkVal = '".$match."'";
        $Result = $con->query($Query);

        if($row = $Result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $NewValue = preg_replace("/\{\{[^{}]+\}\}/", $row["link"], $String);

        }
    }

        echo json_encode($NewValue);

 } 


?>
```

If first occurrence the {{ONE}} should replace with new value with $row["link"],
Secondly replace {{TWO}} With New value so on.

Comment: How about: `$NewValue = str_replace($match, $row["link"], $String);`

Comment: will check your suggestion

Comment: That replaced only one match.

Comment: Use it inside the loop, instead of `preg_replace`

Comment: I wonder if you could use something with [`preg_replace_callback()` like this demo](https://3v4l.org/M7IFD). Not sure if I understand your question right :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the loop on each match, instead of using `preg_replace`, I suggest you to use `str_replace`:

```
if(preg_match_all("/\{\{[^{}]+\}\}/", $lclString, $matches)) {
    $NewValue = $String;
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        $Count++;
        $Query = "SELECT link FROM student WHERE linkVal = '".$match."'";
        $Result = $con->query($Query);

        if($row = $Result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $NewValue = str_replace($match, $row["link"], $NewValue);
            //          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($NewValue);
}
```

Comment: Apart from using `str_replace` - not sure if there is any difference between this and my answer.

Comment: @Michael: What is the output of `echo json_encode($NewValue);`, and what do you expect?

Comment: @NigelRen: Sure that's the only difference, I've commented the question before posting it as an answer, that's why I posted 2min after you.

Comment: But your comment includes the original flaw about continually replacing in the original string.

Comment: @NigelRen: I focused on the way to replace properly then I fixed some error when answering and `str_replace` is much more efficient than `preg_replace`

Comment: able to replace single occurrence.

Comment: @Michael: Insert some debug in your code, what does `$row["link"]` contain (for example)

Comment: $row["link"] contains for example ABC, XYZ, PQR, HGK etc

Comment: On first occurence, I want to replace ABC and Then 2nd XYZ, 3rd PQR as loops.

Comment: @Michael : Add more debug, print `$match`, `$row["link"]`, `$NewValue` before and after the replacement, ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to iterate through your matches.

e.g.

```
$str = "{{ONE}} {{TWO}} {{THREE}} {{FOUR}} {{FIVE}} {{SIX}}";
$replaced = preg_replace_callback('/{{([^{}]*)}}/', function($match) {
// $match[1] contains the current match (first capture group) e.g. ONE
// return your replacement for the current match, e.g. reversed string ENO
return strrev($match[1]);
}, $str);
echo $replaced;
```

Output will be `ENO OWT EERHT RUOF EVIF XIS`

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly simplify your code by fetching all the replacement values in one query:

```
$String = "{{ONE}} {{TWO}} {{THREE}} {{FOUR}} {{FIVE}} {{SIX}}";
if(preg_match_all("/\{\{[^{}]+\}\}/", $String, $matches)) {
    $Query = "SELECT linkVal, link FROM student WHERE linkVal IN('".implode("','", $matches[0])."')";
    $Result = $con->query($Query);
    if ($rows = $Result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $NewValue = str_replace(array_column($rows, 'linkVal'), array_column($rows, 'link'), $String);
    }
    echo json_encode($NewValue);
}
```

Comment: @Michael do you know if the query is returning any results? Can you `var_dump($rows);`?

Comment: query returning multiple different results

Comment: @Michael if the query is returning results the `str_replace` should work - here's an example:https://3v4l.org/ch9HV

Comment: @Michael sorry just realised I had a typo in the code. Can you try again (I've edited the answer)

Comment: @Michael can you please let me know what you get with `var_dump($rows);`? If I could see that I'm sure I could resolve the issue quickly.

Comment: on var_dump() I am getting two different images                                                                             <img src="http://localhost/image1.png">                                                                       <img src="http://localhost/image2.png">

Comment: Second Replacement is happening.

Comment: Only Last Replacement is happening.

Comment: @Michael the images you linked to are on your local server so I can't see them. But it looks like you've found an answer so don't worry about it

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code, you need to ensure that the variable in the `preg_match_all()` is the string your trying to search.

But the main problem is in the replacement part.  You need to replace the current match value (`$match`) and replace it in a new string - currently you always replace the new match in the original string.  Here I create `$NewValue` from the original string and keep replacing values in that...

```
if(preg_match_all("/\{\{[^{}]+\}\}/", $String, $matches)) {
    $NewValue = $String;
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        $Count++;
        $Query = "SELECT link FROM student WHERE linkVal = '".$match."'";
        $Result = $con->query($Query);

        if($row = $Result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $NewValue = preg_replace("/".preg_quote($match)."/", 
                              $row["link"], $NewValue);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($NewValue);

}
```

You should also look into using prepared statements as currently you may be open to SQL Injection problems.

Comment: only one replacement happened.

Comment: replacing two strings with same replacement like {{ONE}} {{TWO}} replacing both with 1 and 1.

Comment: Can you show what value is in `linkVal` and `link` on the `student` table? (As the value of `$match` will be `{{ONE}}`)

Answer (score 0):

The expression we might wish to design here can be like one of these:

```
({{)(.+?)(}})
```

which is only using capturing groups `()`.

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/bVN315/1/)

---

```
(?:{{)(.+?)(?:}})
```

and here we can use non-capturing groups `(?:)`, if we do not wish to keep the `{{` and `}}`.

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/ERVooa/1)

Then, we could simply do the `preg_replace` that we wanted to do.

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?:{{)(.+?)(?:}})/m';
$str = '{{ONE}} {{TWO}} {{THREE}} {{FOUR}} {{FIVE}} {{SIX}}';
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```