# str_replace function not able to replace multiple values

Tags: php, regex

I have set of strings and need to replace them using str)replace as we loop through the query as the query is success need to replace each value in PHP.

```
<?php

include_once("con.php");
$db = new Da();

$con = $db->con();

$lclString = "{{ONE}} {{TWO}} {{THREE}} {{FOUR}} {{FIVE}} {{SIX}}";

 $lclCount = 1;
 if(preg_match_all("/\{\{[^{}]+\}\}/", $lclString, $matches)) {

    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {

        $lclQuery = "SELECT link, link_value FROM student WHERE link_value = '".$match."'";

        $lclResult = $connString->query($lclQuery);

        while($row = $lclResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $lclNewValue = str_replace($match, $row['link'], $lclString);

            }

        }

        echo json_encode($NewValue);

 } 

?>
```

Here only second replacement is happening.

Comment: Isn't this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305762/how-to-loop-through-match-and-replace which you asked yesterday and marked as answered?

Comment: YES, yesterday I did not get an answer so that today I posted once again and after posting I got an answer.

Comment: Don't re-post questions, please. It's bad if needed information is spread across them, and it generates more work for volunteers :(

Comment: Ok, this will not happen once again.

Comment: If you found a solution, then add the answer to the original question and you will eventually be able to mark it as answered.  It would also be useful to add comments to your answer to show what the solution was (I would be interested to see what was happening).

Comment: Ok, Sure I will for future posts.

Comment: Str_replace is amazing and I can replace one thousand term with another one thousand term in single function with only str_replace in one step without preg_replace or preg_match .but your question is unclear. What researches you done .are you sure that problem with function not another variable or even another script or you need scheme to use . You should read more on https://php.net  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

include_once("con.php");
$db = new Da();

$con = $db->con();

$lclString = "{{ONE}} {{TWO}} {{THREE}} {{FOUR}} {{FIVE}} {{SIX}}";

 $lclCount = 1;
 if(preg_match_all("/\{\{[^{}]+\}\}/", $lclString, $matches)) {
 $lclNewValue = $lclString;
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {

    $lclQuery = "SELECT link, link_value FROM student WHERE link_value = '".$match."'";

    $lclResult = $connString->query($lclQuery);

    while($row = $lclResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $lclNewValue = str_replace($match, $row['link'], $lclNewValue);

        }

    }

    echo json_encode($NewValue);

 } 

?>
```